# Coupling with conditional distributions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

I have a question regarding coupling a random variable with the same random variable conditioned on a particular event. The example I will be discussing is taken from "Coupling and Poisson Approximation" by Janson.

Let $r$ balls be thrown independently of each other into $n$ boxes labelled $1,...,n$. Let $p_i$ denote the probability of hitting box $i$. Defined the indicator $I_i = I(\text{box $i$ is empty})$, and let $W=\sum_{i=1}^n I_i$. For $j\neq i$, we may create a coupling of $I_i$ and $I_i | I_j=1$ by removing all balls from box $j$ and redistributing them according to the original distribution, repeating until box $j$ is empty.

While seems obvious that this should be a coupling of $I_i$ and $I_i | I_j=1$, it is not clear to me how I would write down the joint distribution for the coupling if I wanted to rigorously verify that, especially since in the conditional space, our probabilities are normalised by $\mathbb{P}(I_j=1)$. There are several examples of this type in the paper, so I'm hoping if I can understand this simpler one, I can understand the others. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's equivalent but easier to see if you consider "fresh balls" from a countable sequence instead of reusing the old ones that were thrown in box $j$. Here is a coupling. Consider $k$ boxes and a given box $j\le k$ of interest. Consider a countable ordered sequence of iid balls $B_1,B_2, B_3,...$ thrown into the boxes.

- For the distribution $n$ balls conditionally on box $j$ being empty, consider the first $n$ balls of the sequence not falling into box $j$. In other words, if a ball falls in box $j$, forget it and continue throwing balls using the next "fresh" one from the sequence.
- For the unconditional distribution, consider only the first $n$ balls $B_1, B_2,...,B_n$ no matter where they are thrown.

Comment: The second point makes sense to me, it's obvious that this will give the correct marginal. For the first point, while it's obvious to me that this generates every realisation possible given that box $j$ is empty, it's not clear to me why summing all these trajectories will give the correct marginal for the conditional distribution.

Comment: After doing computations with some examples I now see why what you've given gives the correct marginal for the conditional distribution, thanks for the help.